# Can someone explain me the Borg design pattern in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I know this pattern is used in order to create multiple instances with the same state, but i really don't understand how it works.

```
class Borg:
    _shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = self._shared_state



class Singleton(Borg):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Borg.__init__(self)
        self._shared_state.update(kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._shared_state)
```

More specifically, what happens when in the Singleton **init** method I call Borg.**init** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, **class variable** are shared by all instances.

```
class Spam:
    ham = 'ham'

s1 = Spam()
s2 = Spam()

print(s1.ham) # => ham
print(s2.ham) # => ham

Spam.ham = 'egg'

print(s1.ham) # => egg
print(s2.ham) # => egg
```

Second, attrbutes are managed by `self.__dict__`.

```
class Spam:
    pass

s1 = Spam()
s1.__dict__['ham'] = 'ham'
print(s1.ham) # => ham
```

Borg pattern uses this features. `Borg.__shared_dict` is **class variable**.
This behavior occurs because `_shared_dict` is assigned to `self.__dict__` whenever an instance of Singleton is created.